# Exporting to pdf from microsoft office word

Tags: microsoft-office, pdf

As many of you might know Microsoft office (2003 at least) does not support exporting pdf's nativity, What good software is there out there that can easily export a word document into a pdf format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used and like both [pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) and also [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) for making PDF files from windows applications which don't natively support pdf creation.

Comment: CutePDF is good

Comment: Last time I checked, pdfcreator doesn't work on Vista, otherwise, works quite well.

Comment: both work on vista/7 and they both work good, thanks

Comment: Indeed, I can vouch for PDFCreator's working-ness on Vista.

Answer (score 2):

With the risk of sounding like an open source zealot (which I'm not), you should try OpenOffice; it's so way less annoying and faster than MS office that I ditched MSO at home.

Oh, and it also let you nativly save PDF's.

Answer (score 1):

[Pdf 995](http://www.pdf995.com/) is a printer driver that exports to PDF format. The version I use initially came bundled with some tax software, so I don't know if the download product is the same, although I would imagine so. It's pretty easy to use and quite configurable.

Comment: Pdf 995 is good on a single PC, but has major problems on Citrix, so we have had to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supports PDF save-as (almost) out of the box for Office 2007

[2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

PrimoPDF or doPDF

Answer (score -2):

Unbelievable. 4 answers and still nobody mentioned Adobe Acrobat (since you didn't ask for *free* software)

Comment: that's because he just wants to export, not edit pdf.

Comment: @csmba - well, nothing's stopping you for using it just for exporting if you want it that way. And when it comes to "good applications for pdf" I believe adobe's should be on top (or very near) on any list.

Comment: I hate using sledgehammers to swat flies.

Comment: "And when it comes to "good applications for pdf I believe adobe's should be on top (or very near) on any list."

You have got to be kidding. Acrobat is bloated beyond belief; we PDF documents every day and have now turned to CutePDF as Adobe cannot handle certain file sizes, especially image-heavy presentations. CutePDF is quick and light and has yet to fail.

Comment: @fourstar - In the past I've exported documents up to 200+Mb with Acrobat and never had any problems with it. Lots of images, graphs and tables (technical reports). What file sizes were you handling ? Also, I've noticed it doesn't have problems with occationaly displaying full page images like some other editors (Foxit).

Comment: All I can say is that you have been lucky. I wouldn't even have Acrobat installed if I didn't occasionally need to edit/reorder PDFs. There are much lighter PDF export apps as I think this question has established!